# Play Store says my phone doesn't support my own app?

Tags: android

I have these android permissions in my manifest.

```
 android.permission.INTERNET
 android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
 android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
 android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 android.permission.SEND_SMS, android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I have a Sony Xperia Tipo mobile (Sony ST21i). The app page says my phone is not supported by my app. My phone has all the above feature and my app is running good on my phone.

The Google Developer site says the following as the required features though I have not explicitly defined any uses-feature tag in my manifest.

```
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.

Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of android.permission.CAMERA implies android.hardware.camera and 
android.hardware.camera.autofocus as said in Android documentation (see last table in this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

As your device don't have autofocus it is not able to download your app.
You should add :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me out. The aapt tool helped me to validate the "uses feature" before publishing in playstore.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you REQUIRE the autofocus feature. Most phones get filtered out on that.